# How to use git directly on Windows with ssh-agent in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I'm trying to update bare git repo as part of build. On Linux it was relatively simple:

```
dir("/my/git/repo.git") {
    sshagent(['git']) {
        sh "git fetch origin module:module"
    }
}
```

However I cannot figure out how to do it on Windows. I tried:

```
dir("c:\\my\\git\\repo.git") {
    withEnv(["PATH=${env.PATH};C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin"]) {
        sshagent(['git']) {
            sh "git fetch origin module:module"
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails:

```
Could not find ssh-agent: IOException: Cannot run program "ssh-agent": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Check if ssh-agent is installed and in PATH
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see ssh-agent in:

```
C:\>where ssh-agent
C:\tools\gits\latest\usr\bin\ssh-agent.exe
```

You need to make sure your `%PATH%` (as seen by the user executing the Jenkins job) includes `Git\bin`, `Git\usr\bin`, `Git\mingw64\bin`.
(Replace `Git` by the Git installation path folder)

After executing a job (even failed), look for the link "Environment Variables": you will see exactly who was running the job (`USERNAME`) and the `PATH` used.