# Jenkins, git 'advanced' commands (fetch, diff etc) and ssh-agent (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, ssh

We have x86 Jenkins running on Windows Server 2016.  No issues with pull of repo over ssh, both for projects and with git plugin in the pipeline.

Now I would like to be able to execute a 'git diff' command after a fetch from origin.  I installed the Jenkins plugin "sshagent" and am attempting to execute the git commands from that context.  From that plugins page it appears I no longer need to use Tomcat Native Libraries (quote: As of 1.14 unnecessary if ssh-agent is installed)

My direct issue is the error "Check if ssh-agent is installed and in PATH".  I would prefer not to use Tomcat version if possible.  I suppose I am trying to understand why every search I do implies ssh-agent.exe should be part of git, but it is not in my 'bin' folder.

Open to other ways to accomplish the stated goal (execute git diff), including foregoing ssh connection to the git server, but that also looks to be not straightforward.

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616958/how-to-use-git-directly-on-windows-with-ssh-agent-in-jenkins

Comment: thanks - my issue appears to be ssh-agent is not in the git bin dir.  If I can understand the why of that I will definitely add it to the path

Comment: It looks like this would work for the https option, though I would prefer to use ssh.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570075/tag-a-repo-from-a-jenkins-workflow-script/33630506#33630506

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being fairly straightforward, ssh-agent.exe was in git/usr/bin not git/bin. adding it to path per Druta suggestion resolved